# NSURLCredential creation returning null

Tags: ios, iphone, certificate, keychain, nsurlcredential

I am trying to create a `NSURLCredential` by using the `+credentialWithIdentity:certificates:persistence:` method. However it's returning nil.

I've done the following steps. First I create a private and public key, then generated a certificate and add it to my keychain.
The first problem, when I do this:

```
static const uint8_t certificateIdentifier[] = "test.certificate";    
NSData * certificateTag = [NSData dataWithBytes:certificateIdentifier length:sizeof(certificateIdentifier)];
SecCertificateRef cert = SecCertificateCreateWithData(NULL, (__bridge CFDataRef) certificadoData);
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassCertificate forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[dictionary setObject:certificateTag forKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrApplicationTag];
[dictionary setObject:(__bridge id)(cert) forKey:(__bridge id<NSCopying>)(kSecValueRef)];
OSStatus status = SecItemAdd((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)dictionary, NULL);
```

The status tell me that my `certificateTag` is an invalid argument.
If I don't put this tag and I can put the certificate on my keychain, then inside the method

```
(void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveAuthenticationChallenge:(NSURLAuthenticationChallenge *)challenge
```

I put

```
SecIdentityRef myIdentity;
SecCertificateRef myCertificate;

NSMutableDictionary * queryCertificate = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[queryCertificate setObject:(__bridge id)kSecClassIdentity forKey:(__bridge id)kSecClass];
[queryCertificate setObject:[NSNumber numberWithBool:YES] forKey:(__bridge id)kSecReturnRef];

OSStatus status = SecItemCopyMatching((__bridge CFDictionaryRef)queryCertificate, (CFTypeRef *)&myIdentity);

status = SecIdentityCopyCertificate(myIdentity, &myCertificate);

const void *certs[] = { myCertificate };
CFArrayRef certsArray = CFArrayCreate(NULL, certs, 1, NULL);
NSURLCredential *credential = [NSURLCredential credentialWithIdentity:myIdentity certificates:(__bridge NSArray*)certsArray persistence:NSURLCredentialPersistencePermanent];

[[challenge sender] useCredential:credential forAuthenticationChallenge:challenge];
```

I got the identity and certificate right, but the credential keeps returning nothing, not an error, just null.
Any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first part of my question, I was trying to add a kSecAttrApplicationTag in a kSecClassCertificate, but the kSecAttrApplicationTag is only accepted in kSecClassKey.

In the second part, the result of the credential (`<NSURLCredential: 0x1e20d140>: (null)`) was right, this "null" doesn't means that the value is actually null. Keeping this way my code work fine.